# How to update an active windows form textbox from a value in a second form?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have a Windows Form (let's call it `Form1`) that opens a second windows form (`Form2`) to make the user select something from a comboBox.

```
// create form1
var Form1 = new Form1();
Form1.Show();

// event to open form2
private void openForm2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 Form2= new Form2();
    Form2.Show();
}
```

After selecting an item in the comboBox, the user clicks on the "Update" button to update a `textBox` in `Form1` with the selected value.

```
private void updateForm1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Form1.textBox1 is not accessible
    }
```

I know how to pass a value from `Form1` to `Form2`, but how can I pass a value from `Form2` back to the active `Form1` ? I can't access the active `Form1` without recreating the form.

Comment: Create a method, pass the data/text/info.  Let each form fiddle with their own controls

Comment: When you load the second form you can add bind a formClosing() method to it. In this method since all the controls in the form are still there you can access to their values. Check the following msdn article. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not sure how to do that, can you post an answer with a brief example ?

Comment: Ok i found a way to make it work. I'll post the answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by passing an event handler.

```
// propertie in form1 to hold the form2 instance to get the value back
private Form2 _form2;
public Form2 form2
{
    get { return _form2; }
    set { this._form2= value; }
}

// opens the form1
var Form1 = new Form1();
Form1.Show();

// event to open form2
private void openForm2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 Form2= new Form2();
    Form2.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(getValueFromForm2);
    Form2.Show();

    this.form2 = Form2;
}

// event to retrieve the value and update textbox of form1
private void getValueFromForm2(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = this.form2.Controls.Find("theControlWithTheValue", true)[0];

    // control is a listbox
    ListBox lbox = ctrl as ListBox;

    // update form1 textbox
    textBoxInForm1.Text = lbox.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```